Run a WordPress blog (subdirectory) in a Laravel WebApp - SEO Concerns
I've developed a Laravel WebApplicaiton and now i'm in need of creating a WordPress Blog in a subdirectiory (domain.com/blog)
I have concerns regarding SEO and if this new installation with canibalize my main domain?
Anybody has any expreience with this?

Can you rephrase your question so that it can be answered? This isn't a discussion forum so you need to phrase it in a way that you can mark an answer as the correct answer for all people with this question. Note that you might not get the best SEO specific answers here as this isn't an SEO stack, it's a programming stack

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I don't see any problems with this setup. For simplicity place a sitemap index in your main Laravel application that points to your laravel sitemap and your wordpress sitemap. Then you can submit that sitemap index to google and bing. You can read more about sitemap indexes here:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/large-sitemaps
